# Unexpected LSTM layer output in PyBrain

Tags: neural-network, pybrain, lstm

I am using an LSTM layer to multiplex among several memory cells. That said, having several input options, I want to feed only one of them to the hidden layer. I arranged the input to LSTM in such a way, so it would select an apropriate cell based on the input_gate, forget_gate, and output_gate I pass to it in addition to the cell_input.

However, it seems that the LSTM layer transforms the values of the memory cells, while I would expect it to pass them to the output as-is.

For example, I am passing the following input, which I printed in groups corresponding to input_gate, forget_gate, cell_input, and output_gate for convenience:

```
ig: [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.] 
fg: [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
ci: [ 0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5  0. ]
og: [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
```

I want the LSTM layer to only pass `ci[0]`, `ci[1]`, and `ci[5]` to the output as the `og` group indicates.
However, what I see in the output buffer is different:

```
LSTM out: [ 0.16597414  0.23799096  0.1135163   0.1135163   0.1135163   0.]
```

While not absolutely meaningless to me (the 0-th and 1-th entries are slightly greater than the rest) this output is not the `[.5 .5 0. 0. 0.]` that I expected.

From what I learned about LSTM, it doesn't seem that there is any transition function from the memory cells to the actual output.

Answer (score 1):

Silly question, of course: the output is clamped by a sigmoid.